# Qual a diferença entre os seguintes métodos?

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em JSF e me deparei com os seguintes métodos e quero saber a diferença entre eles.

```
((HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                     .getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate();
```

e

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dois trechos de código executam a mesma ação, que é invalidar uma sessão.
A diferença está em de que classe vem o método. O `invalidate` é originário da classe 
[`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate()), já o `invalidateSession` é da classe [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#invalidateSession()).
Repare que no trecho de código que você usa o `invalidate` você está fazendo um *casting* da sessão recuperada do `FacesContext` para `HttpSession` e assim podendo acessar o método.
É interessante acrescentar que a implementação do `invalidateSession`, vai apenas executar o `invalidate` da `HttpSession`.